# How do I clear recent emoji input history on Windows 10 emoji panel?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, privacy, history, emoji

<kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> provides an emoji panel, but it shows recent emojis; How do I clear recent emojis?

[image: emoji panel]